# Storytelling Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Can someone please identify how this site has the effect of sliding through pages? Mainly how it pulls down one page up and onto another. Is it Javascript? I think it is very well done.

http://hire.visualidiot.com/typestacks

Thanks!

Joe

Comment: @j08691 How to know by seeing view source?

Comment: Good 1 @j08691 - incredibly insightful

I know it links to the page below, but I am not sure what animates the page pulling it down

Comment: Really nice example of whole page animation, glad I opened this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened it in Safari and disabled JavaScript.  The sliding effect went away (although it degrades nicely).  Clearly JavaScript must be involved somehow.  Okay, so I popped open Chrome Developer Tools and looked at the resources.  There's a script called [handler.js](http://hire.visualidiot.com/assets/js/handler.js).  I opened it up and sure enough there's some nicely documented code.  It looks like it's using [jQuery animations](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  Take a look at the script.  You should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 4):

helixed's answer explains how they did it. However if you want to recreate the effect yourself have a look at using Parallaxjs rather than taking potentially copy-written code.

See the demo site: http://stolksdorf.github.com/Parallaxjs/

And source: https://github.com/stolksdorf/parallaxjs/

Edit: There is a bug with that website, try holding down the arrow key for a few seconds before letting go.